Error in Boosted Regression Tree model with offset
I'm working with boosted regression tree models (BRTs) to predict the probability of occurence of a dolphin species. For that I have presence/absence data and several environmental variables. The occurrence data is split in segments and I want to use the length of the segments as an offset in the model, to account for effort in the data collection.
I'm using the gbm.step() function from dismo package to fit the model.
brt<-gbm.step(data=df, gbm.x=c(6,7,12,42,43,15,45,53,93,41,81,87,97), gbm.y = 4, offset = offset, family="bernoulli", tree.complexity=3, learning.rate = 0.01, bag.fraction = 0.6)

I defined offset as the log(length of segments)
offset<-log(df$eff_length)

> head(offset)
[1] 9.017928 9.171184 9.239406 9.367430 9.264165 9.233178
> summary(offset)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  8.987   9.065   9.146   9.181   9.265   9.615 

When I run the model it gives me repeatedly this warning:
Warning in gbm::predict.gbm(model.list[[i]], x.data[pred.mask, , drop = FALSE],  :
  predict.gbm does not add the offset to the predicted values.

Followed by this error:
Error in if (cv.loss.values[j] > cv.loss.values[j - 1]) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

I've tried to include the fold.vector=offset as it looked like the error has something to do with the cross-validation process but it gave me the same warnings and error.
What I'm missing here? Does it have something to do with the fact that is a Bernoulli type of distribution?
